# Stronger condition then ultrametric condition on metric space

Tags: analysis, number-theory, formal-languages

A metric space $(X,d)$ is called an ultrametric space if it is a metric space and fulfills the stronger triangle inequality (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space))
$$
 d(x,y) \le \max\{ d(x,z), d(z, y) \}.
$$
Examples are the Cantor-Space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ with the common-prefix-metric $d(\xi, \eta) = 1/k$ where $k$ is the smallest $k > 0$ such that $\xi_k \ne \eta_k$, or the $p$-adic numbers. Now is there anything known about spaces which fulfill the even stronger requirement
$$
 d(x,y) = \max\{ d(x,z), d(z, y) \}.
$$
for pairwise different points $x,y,z$. The Cantor-Space with the common-prefix-metric is an example.

**EDIT**: Initially I wrote: $d(x,y) = \min\{ d(x,z), d(z, y) \}$, which always induces the discrete space, see the comment.

Comment: yes, thank you for noticing, I updated my question. To exlude the discrete space all three $x,y,z$ have to be pairwise different.

Comment: Even so, pick $x\neq y$. Then $B_{d(x,y)/2}(x) = \{x\}$ if $d(x,y) = \min \{d(x,z),d(y,z)\}$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I confused something, I edited the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cantor space does not satisfy this stronger requirement: if $x = \langle 1 , 0 , 0 , \ldots \rangle$, $y = \langle 1, 1, 0 , 0 \ldots \rangle$ and $z = \langle 0, 0, 0, \ldots \rangle$, then $d (x,y) = 1/2$ and $d(x,z) = d(y,z) = 1/1$.

Note that your condition implies that all (non-degenerate) triangles are "equilateral": given distinct points $x,y,z$, we know that $d(x,y)$ must equal the greater of $d(x,z)$ and $d(y,z)$, and without loss of generality we may assume that it $d(x,y) = d(x,z)$.  But now that same condition implies that $d(y,z) = \max \{ d(x,y) , d (x,z) \} = d(x,y) = d(x,z)$.

This in turn shows that in such a metric space there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x,y) = \delta$ for all distinct $x,y$, resulting in a discrete topological space.